# override Add new record functionality in jTable

Tags: javascript, jquery-jtable

I am using jTable plugin and every thing is working fine. What I want to do is to redirect the user to a new screen instead of displaying the default pop-up form when the user clicks the **Add new Record** button.

Although I can hide the default button and then add a custom button that redirects to the new URL, I want to know if it can be done by just using some configurations in the jTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use the [toolbar option](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/GeneralOptions#genopt-toolbar) to add a custom button instead of using the default "Add New Record" button.

```
toolbar: {
    items: [{
        icon: '/images/add.png',
        text: 'Add New Record',
        click: function () {
            //Your custom code would go here
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: thanks, so far this seems to have what I was hoping for.